# Issue with Integration of Spring Security SAML Java application with ADFS 4

Tags: spring-security, saml-2.0, adfs4.0

I am trying to integrate SSO in an existing java/jsp based application(SP) with help of  Spring Security SAML extension and ADFS 4(IP). After I land in the ADFS SSO page from SP login link and enter credentials, application is not able to validate the ADFS response and giving **"HTTP Status 401 - Authentication Failed: Error validating SAML message"** error. 
However from logs I can see the Assertion is already decrypted successfully and Attributes are being printed. So I am not able to understand why it is giving Authentication Failed error. Pl. help. I am providing log data below. The java application is hosted in Tomcat server.

*20-08-2019 11:52:20,003 DEBUG org.apache.xml.security.signature.Reference:? - Verification successful for URI "#_530eaef7-3196-431c-bef8-36fc7c76ef27"
20-08-2019 11:52:20,003 DEBUG org.apache.xml.security.signature.Manifest:? - The Reference has Type 
20-08-2019 11:52:20,006 TRACE org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext:322 - Publishing event in Root WebApplicationContext: org.springframework.security.authentication.event.AuthenticationFailureServiceExceptionEvent[source=org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLAuthenticationToken@43b19eef: Principal: null; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: false; Details: null; Not granted any authorities]
20-08-2019 11:52:20,006 DEBUG org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLProcessingFilter:346 - Authentication request failed: org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationServiceException: Error validating SAML message
20-08-2019 11:52:20,006 DEBUG org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLProcessingFilter:347 - Updated SecurityContextHolder to contain null Authentication
20-08-2019 11:52:20,007 DEBUG org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLProcessingFilter:348 - Delegating to authentication failure handler org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler@90f53ff
20-08-2019 11:52:20,007 DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler:56 - No failure URL set, sending 401 Unauthorized error
20-08-2019 11:52:20,007 DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository:269 - SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.*

Comment: *Principal: null* could possibly mean the token lacks a claim with specific type your Spring client expects. Make sure what actual claim type is required and that ADFS is configured to issue this claim.

Comment: The Spring activity is happening on the framework and I have not set any specific claim separately. Please let me know how to find out which claim is being expected by the framework.